# Check if JavaFX Platform is running

Tags: java, javafx

There is no method such as `javafx.application.Platform.isRunning()`.

Can I check somehow else if the platform has been started?

I would like to modify my `javafx.util.concurrent.Task` classes to call `updateMessage()`, etc. only if the Platform is actually running.

That would be useful in a test setup.

If I test, I run into `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized`

I think this could be easily avoided by something like

```
if(Platform.isRunning()){
    updateMessage("Doing work");
}
```

Comment: A `Task` basically assumes the FX Application Thread is already running anyway. For example, it is going to schedule changes to its `state` property on the FX Application thread when it is scheduled and starts running, etc. You probably need to write code (even in your unit tests) that ensures the platform is running before starting a task.

Comment: I usually just call `task.call()` for testing purposes. This does not alter the state of the task and should be save to do even without a running platform. (If I do not call the methods mentioned above in the `call()` method.)

Comment: OK, but the assumption is still made; especially if you are calling `updateXXX(...)` methods in `call(...)`. You're basically proposing modifying (or at least introducing guards) in your code solely to handle the test environment. If you want to test `Task.call()`, you need the FX platform running. If you want to test functionality that is invoked in the `call()` method, refactor that functionality into another class and unit test that class.

Comment: You are right. The reason why I did not do such refactorings so far is that I want to notify about progress (status messages, progress-done information). I would need some kind of ProgressMonitor (e.g. `org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor`) to propagate such information from my `Callable` to the `Task`. Unfortunately, such thing is difficult to implement when using `Task`, since here progress monitoring is done via protected methods instead of a separate progress monitor object.

Comment: If I need to monitor progress in an external (JavaFX-agnostic) class implementing some process, I usually just define a `DoubleConsumer progressUpdate;` field in that class. Then if I use it from a `Task`, all I need is `myProcess.setProgressUpdate(p -> updateProgress(p, 1.0));`

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: I tried it using a StringConsumer for updating the progress message. I will refactor further to use a DoubleConsumer for the progress. Very nice solution, thanks a lot! You can make an answer from your comment, I will upvote.

Comment: Probably you should rewrite the question so that it is about refactoring a task so that the process you are wrapping is not dependent on JavaFX (which I think is what you're really asking).

Comment: I think this question here is still valid, so I opened a new one about the task refactoring https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47419949/propagate-progress-information-from-callable-to-task

Answer (score 0):

**Preface:**

Too late for the party, but this library of mine eliminates exactly this issued.

https://github.com/davidweber411/SimpleJavaFxApplicationBase

For more information, like documentation, check out the homepage https://wedasoft.com/projects/simple-java-fx-application-base/.

**Solution:**

Take a look at the class `SimpleJavaXTestBase`.

https://github.com/davidweber411/SimpleJavaFxApplicationBase/blob/master/src/main/java/com/wedasoft/simpleJavaFxApplicationBase/testBase/SimpleJavaFxTestBase.java

Either use my library from Maven Central or copy the needed classes into your needed project:

Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.wedasoft</groupId>
    <artifactId>simplejavafxapplicationbase</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Gradle:

```
implementation("com.wedasoft:simplejavafxapplicationbase:1.7.0")
```

**Documentation:**

https://wedasoft.com/projects/simple-java-fx-application-base/sjfxab-version-1-7-0/#testing-suite