# Propagate Progress Information from Callable to Task

Tags: java, javafx

I am using `javafx.concurrent.Task` to do background work in our JavaFX application.

When unit testing such tasks, I usually just invoke `task.call()`. In contrast to `task.run()`, this will not change the state of the task (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46778025/task-run-vs-task-call-and-composition-of-multiple-tasks-into-one), *please vote for undelete*). If I do not call any `update..()` method, I can call `task.call()` even without the JavaFX Platform running.

I would like to refactor this approach to be **independent from a running JavaFX environment**, and **move the implementation of the `call()` method** into a JavaFX independent `Callable`.

Testing this independent class would be more simple and this callable can be easily used from within a task.

The question is now how can I update the callable's progress and propagate this progress information to the calling task?

`Task` does progress updating via protected `update...()` methods and does not use a dedicated object for that (e.g. like `org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor`) which would make delegating this functionality easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note first that while the `javafx.concurrent` package relies on the FX Toolkit to be running, there is no such requirement on the JavaFX Properties classes. So, as long as you only access a JavaFX Property from a single thread, it would be perfectly valid to use JavaFX properties in classes that you wanted to use without requiring the FX Toolkit is running.

So for example, you could do:

```
public class MyProcess implements Callable<SomeData> {

    private final ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper progress = new ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper();

    public ReadOnlyDoubleProperty progressProperty() {
        return progress.getReadOnlyProperty() ;
    }

    public final double getProgress() {
        return progressProperty().get();
    }

    @Override
    public SomeData call() {
        final int numSteps = ... ;
        SomeData data = new SomeData();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < numSteps ; i++) {
            progress.set(1.0*i/numSteps);
            data.update(i);
        }
        return data ;
    }
}
```

This class will run fine and doesn't depend on the FX Toolkit running. You can wrap it in a task as follows:

```
public class MyProcessTask extends Task<SomeData> {

    @Override
    protected SomeData call() throws Exception {
        MyProcess process = new MyProcess();
        process.progressProperty().addListener((obs, oldProgress, newProgress) ->
            updateProgress(newProgress, 1.0));
        return process.call();
    }
}
```

If you want you `Callable` implementation to be independent of JavaFX on an API level (not just in the sense of not requiring the toolkit to be running), it is pretty easy to implement the appropriate callbacks using the `java.util.function` API. For example, you could refactor the above as

```
public class MyProcess implements Callable<SomeData> {

    private DoubleConsumer progressUpdate = d -> {} ; // no-op
    private double progress ;

    public void setProgressUpdate(DoubleConsumer progressUpdate) {
        this.progressUpdate = progressUpdate ;
    }

    public final double getProgress() {
        return progress;
    }

    private void setProgress(double progress) {
        this.progress = progress ;
        progressUpdate.accept(progress);
    }

    @Override
    public SomeData call() {
        final int numSteps = ... ;
        SomeData data = new SomeData();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < numSteps ; i++) {
            setProgress(1.0*i/numSteps) ;
            data.update(i);
        }
        return data ;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class MyProcessTask extends Task<SomeData> {

    @Override
    protected SomeData call() throws Exception {
        MyProcess process = new MyProcess();
        process.setProgressUpdate(p -> updateProgress(p, 1.0));
        return process.call();
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I can use a similar approach for `updateMessage()`. But what about cancelling? Would it make sense to use a `Consumer<Boolean>` for that?

Comment: `Callable`s are not cancelable in the same sense that `Task`s are. "Cancelled" is part of the `Task`-specific state that is updated on the FX Application Thread (so it falls in the same category as `RUNNING`, `SUCCEEDED`, etc).

Comment: So what would be the best way to listen for a cancel request by the user? Check `Thread.isInterrupted()`?

Comment: Nice (if old) article [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05236/index.html) on cancelation and interruptability in Java threads in general. You can easily wrap this in your `Task` and update the cancelled state accordingly if the wrapped callable is interrupted.

Comment: By *Brian Goetz*, so I guess its timeless ;) thanks a lot!